# Display search results inside div and add new results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I've been looking for a good how to on this topic for the last 4 days and could not find any. Even worse; I'm not able to think of a good description of what I'm trying to achieve.

For example Dropbox has the functionality of what I would like to implement on my own website. If you login into dropbox you can upload files. When you upload files one by one the UI stacks the results (filename, location, etc.)  into a div element. There are other websites who also do this; Namecheap, for example, when you search for a domain and click add to cart you see the domain show up on the right side, where you have the option to delete it.

What I would like to do:
Have a page with a search box that queries my database for objects and displays the results into a div element below. Everytime the user does a new search the results in that div element will change. But if the user clicks on the 'add to' button the object must move from the `search_results` div element to another div element on the same page where all the previous selected elements are also listed. The user is then able to delete the object from the list or alter the values of the object such as the amount.

Like I said; I've been pulling my hair out because I cannot find it... I'm feeling really stupid right now :( Does anybody know what the technicall name of such a functionality is?

**EDIT**

The comment below from Quasimodo's clone and yuriy636 pushed me in the right direction. After searching with there terminology I've found this page:
https://cartjs.org/

The second example is exactly what I was looking for. However I'm not able to upvote a comment but I do like to give credits to both for helping me out!

Comment: show us what you have try. Olso [jquey](https://jquery.com/) will help you with your project

Comment: DOM manipulation, AJAX?

Comment: I don't really think there is a "functionality" name for all that. Sounds like an complete webapp. You have to split what you want into components: first the search part, you can do this with AJAX(you request the server and then append the results). Then the cart, you can do that with jQuery, cloning the result element maybe. That for front-end. For back-end you have to design the database and then the code for respond to AJAX (in JSON maybe, for easier manipulation).

Comment: @RafaelShkembi don't be ridiculous

Comment: Am i whrong @PeHaa ?

Comment: I know jquery is great and does all the things, but there is no need for blanket statements on vague questions like that imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite vague but I think what I've done below can at least nudge you in the right direction.

Let's say you have something like this - a div to hold your search results, each of which is it's own div with class `result`, and a separate div to hold the 'moved' ones:

```
<div id="searchResults">
    <div class="result">This is one search result.</div>
    <div class="result">This is another result.</div>
</div>

<div id="chosenResults"></div>
```

Now, we can use JQuery to put in the "move" functionality:

```
$(document).ready(function() { //On page load
    $('.result').click(function() { //When element with class "result" is clicked
        $(this).detach().appendTo('#chosenResults'); //Remove it form the results list, add it to the other
    });
});
```

**Here it is in action:**  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GqBxEp

I'm not sure where you're at in regards to the actual data retrieval, etc, however I figured knocking out the front-end as I have above may be useful for you.

Comment: As this is an official answer to my question with a code example that works; I'll upvote this one as the correct answer :-)

Comment: @Robbert Much appreciated! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard the term **infinite list** and **infinite scroll**, Wikipedia uses '*lazy or delayed evaluation*': https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation#Delayed_evaluation