# Jquery replace not clone

Tags: jquery

I'm using replaceWith() to move a element to another parent element in DOM. But it makes a copy of it, without removing. So the element remains in the place, but a copy is made in the other parent element. How can i just move the element to other place?

Comment: document.getElementById("target").appendChild(document.getElementById("movethis"));

Comment: Can you supply a simple example to show how you're calling `replaceWith`, and what's happening in the DOM (and what you want to have happen instead)? Your described behavior -- that `replaceWith` clones instead of moves its argument -- is contrary to the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/): "... the selected element replaces the target by being moved from its old location, not by being cloned.".

Comment: As @apsillers asked, we need an example, because when used correctly, the element is moved and not cloned : https://jsfiddle.net/am4mb3gq/

Comment: If, on the other hand, your stack as more than 1 element, it will indeed clone the replacement : https://jsfiddle.net/am4mb3gq/2/. Check that your original stack has only 1 element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have the following HTML:

```
<div id="container1">
    <div id="childDiv"></div>
</div>
<div id="container2">

</div>
```

You could do the following:

```
$("#childDiv").detach().appendTo("#container2");
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/459usn9x/1/

**EDIT:** To first clear the contents of `container2` before adding elements, you could do the following:

```
$("#container2").empty();
$("#childDiv").detach().appendTo("#container2");
```

Comment: this works better, only, is it also possible to first remove the content of #container2?

Comment: haha added the detach just after my answer :D i like it, here to help anyway ^^

Comment: In all honesty I only saw your answer *after* adding the `detach()`. This isn't the first time I've answered the question ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38678103/2026606)), but I appreciate you being kind in pointing it out.

Comment: no pb, i'm not here for rep ;) "only mountains don't meet themselves" we say in my country, talking about synchronicity..

Answer (score 0):

use `$.append()` or `$.appendTo()`. Like `$('#element').appendTo('#place-to-move-it');`. That will move `#element` to `#place-to-move-it`.

Answer (score 0):

to do this consistently on various devices, use this:

```
$('#elementID').detach().appendTo($('#targetID'));
```

`detach` keeps the link of the element with others, whereas `remove` doesn't. And it seems that appendTo used alone creates a copy on certain devices.